# Можно ли сортировать БД с внешней переменной

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Вопрос таков, есть БД `MySQL`, в одном столбце записаны даты, которые должны произойти, в формате `UNIX`. Можно ли через `SQL` передать текущее время и произвести сортировку от события, которое раньше всего произойдет, до самого дальнего. Если событие уже произошло, то его не учитывать. Если да, то как должен выглядеть запрос? Как можно передать и сравнить текущее время?

Comment: А зачем его передавать ? В БД есть свои функции, `unix_timestamp()` возвращает текущий unixtime (или если передать конкретную дату, то на эту дату). А дальше просто ограничиваете в where все события только больше этого времени и сортироете опять же просто по времени

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> в одном столбце записаны даты, которые должны произойти, в формате UNIX

То есть это формат данных INT UNSIGNED? Тогда запрос такой:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE uts > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() ORDER BY uts;
```

Если же тип столбца `TIMESTAMP` или `DATETIME`, то сравнивать нужно с `NOW()`:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE eventtime > NOW() ORDER BY eventtime;
```

При сравнении это работает нормально, в том числе с индексами. Однако, попытка использовать, например, разницу дат (минус), хранимых в столбцах таких типов, приводит к идиотскому результату и необходимости применять функции, которые делают невозможным использование индексов.

Comment: Спасибо большое